# Replacement of "input" field by a simple "drop down box" not working in php code?

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I encounter an ennoying problem which I can not solve and keeps me busy already 1 day.
In the checkout page of my ecommerce Opencart2 program, people get an overview of their products in the cart before they are transferred to the payment page. At the checkout page, they still have the possibility to change the desired quantity of the products. When they change the quantity, they have to click on the refresh button to reculate the cart total.

In the original opencart script, the quantity can be changed by means of a simple input field. But I want to replace this quantity input field by a drop down list based on the number of products in stock (so they can never exceed the stock quantity). I have applied this succesfully throughout all my website (intermediate cart display, product pages, etcetera). But only at the final checkout page, it is not working. The drop down list nicely appears and is showing the possible quantities from 1, 2, 3 ... to maximum quantity) when they click on the arrow of the drop down.

[Dropdown example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wICj4.jpg)

But when they select a quantity and click on the refresh button, they are returned to the cart overview page telling that there is no product anymore in the cart.

I assume that the quantity is not (empty) or not properly (value zero) posted. Please could somebody have a look at the scripts below and check if there is a possible code error? It's driving me crazy and it would make my day. Besides, is there an easy way (mozilla addon) to check the quantity value that is passed between the different pages.

Thanks,
SabKo

1. The original code in the cart.tpl page with the input field has the following code (and is working):

   ```
                   <td class="text-left quantity">
                   <div class="input-group btn-block" style="max-width: 200px;">
                       <input type="text" name="quantity[<?php echo $product[version_compare(VERSION, '2.1', '<') ? 'key' : 'cart_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" size="1" class="form-control" />
                       <span class="input-group-btn">
                           <button type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_update; ?>" data-product-key="<?php echo $product[version_compare(VERSION, '2.1', '<') ? 'key' : 'cart_id']; ?>,<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-update" ><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                           <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" data-product-key="<?php echo $product[version_compare(VERSION, '2.1', '<') ? 'key' : 'cart_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger  btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
                       </span>
                   </div>
               </td>
   ```
2. I have changed the script in the cart.tpl page as following:

   ```
                   <td class="text-left quantity">
                    <div class="input-group btn-block" style="max-width: 200px;">

                        <select name="quantity[<?php echo $product[version_compare(VERSION, '2.1', '<') ? 'key' : 'cart_id']; ?>]" class="form-control_cart" id="input-quantity" value="<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" >
                        <?php foreach (range($product['minimum'], $product['stockhoeveelheid'], 1) as $stap) {
                             if ($stap == $product['quantity']) {
                                   echo "<option value='$stap' selected>$stap</option>";
                             } else {
                                   echo "<option value='$stap'>$stap</option>";
                             }
                           }  ?>
                        </select>

                       <span class="input-group-btn">
                           <button type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_update; ?>" data-product-key="<?php echo $product[version_compare(VERSION, '2.1', '<') ? 'key' : 'cart_id']; ?>,<?php echo $product['quantity']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-update" ><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                           <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" data-product-key="<?php echo $product[version_compare(VERSION, '2.1', '<') ? 'key' : 'cart_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger  btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button>
                       </span>
                   </div>
               </td>
   ```
3. The class "btn-update" initiates the following script in the checkout.tpl:

   ```
   $(document).delegate('.checkout-product .input-group .btn-update', 'click', function () {
   var key = $(this).attr('data-product-key');
   var qty  = $('input[name="quantity[' + key + ']"]').val();
   $.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?route=journal2/checkout/cart_update',
       type: 'post',
       data: {
           key: key,
           quantity: qty
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       beforeSend: function() {
           triggerLoadingOn();
           $('#cart > button > a > span').button('loading');
           $('.checkout-cart').addClass('checkout-loading');
       },
       complete: function() {
           triggerLoadingOff();
           $('#cart > button > a > span').button('reset');
       },
       success: function(json) {
           setTimeout(function () {
               $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
           }, 100);

           if (json['redirect']) {
               location = json['redirect'];
           } else {
               $('#cart ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');

               $(document).trigger('journal_checkout_reload_payment');
               $(document).trigger('journal_checkout_reload_shipping');
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   });

   ```
   $(document).delegate('.checkout-product .input-group .btn-delete', 'click', function () {
   var key = $(this).attr('data-product-key');
   $.ajax({
       url: 'index.php?route=journal2/checkout/cart_delete',
       type: 'post',
       data: {
           key: key
       },
       dataType: 'json',
       beforeSend: function() {
           triggerLoadingOn();
           $('#cart > button > a > span').button('loading');
           $('.checkout-cart').addClass('checkout-loading');
       },
       complete: function() {
           triggerLoadingOff();
           $('#cart > button > a > span').button('reset');
       },
       success: function(json) {
           setTimeout(function () {
               $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
           }, 100);

           if (json['redirect']) {
               location = json['redirect'];
           } else {
               $('#cart ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');

               $(document).trigger('journal_checkout_reload_payment');
               $(document).trigger('journal_checkout_reload_shipping');
           }
       }
   });
   ```

   });
4. The cart_update code at my checkout.php page is the following:

   ```
   public function cart_update() {
   $key = Journal2Utils::getProperty($this->request->post, 'key');
   $qty = Journal2Utils::getProperty($this->request->post, 'quantity');
   $this->cart->update($key, $qty);

   $json = array();

   if (!$this->checkCart()) {
       $json['redirect'] = Journal2Utils::link('checkout/cart');
   } else {
       $json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_items'), $this->cart->countProducts() + (isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) ? count($this->session->data['vouchers']) : 0), Journal2Utils::currencyFormat($this->model_journal2_checkout->getTotal()));
   }

   echo json_encode($json);
   exit;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your trouble:

```
// As you can see, you're still trying to fetch the value from the input/textbox when you've changed it to a select.
var qty  = $('input[name="quantity[' + key + ']"]').val();

// So change the above like so:
var qty  = $('select[name="quantity[' + key + ']"]').val();
```

Hope that helps and you can carry on with your work :)

Comment: Hello Morgs, Thank you for this solution. I finally got it working now! I am not so experimented with javascript. and spent all evening yesterday trying a lot of things.... Your help was really appreciated! Regards, SabKo